# Multiple dokku apps one domain

Tags: nginx, docker, dokku

The behavior I want:

If the user goes to `http://www.example.com/{anything-but-admin}` one dokku app responds.
However if the user goes to `http://www.example.com/admin` a different dokku app responds.

Does dokku provide a simple way to do this?  I believe I would have to disable the [proxy port mapping](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/proxy-management/#proxy-port-mapping) and add a [custom nginx implementation](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/#managing-proxy-port-mappings), but even if I do that, the docs specify

> If a proxy is disabled, Dokku will bind your container's port to a random port on the host for every deploy, e.g. `0.0.0.0:32771->5000/tcp`.

If this is the correct thing to do, how do I force a static port number, so I can add that port number to my custom nginx configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy two apps and have one of the apps reference the other's upstream.

Comment: Is this by manually editing one of the apps nginx config or is there a way to have dokku manage this?

Comment: You'll need to customize your `nginx.conf.sigil`. Checkout the nginx docs on the dokku docs site for more information.

Comment: For anyone looking at this issue, here is a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046497/1515875