# Exposing websockets port through same location dokku

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, django-channels, dokku

I have a django project where I run my web and django channels as separate procs in the `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application
socket: daphne django_project.asgi:application
```

And have exposed `ws`/`wss` using `dokku proxy:ports-add web ws:80:8000 wss:443:8000` (`web` is my dokku app name):

```
=====> web proxy information
       Proxy enabled:                 true
       Proxy port map:                http:80:5000 https:443:5000 ws:80:8000 wss:443:8000
       Proxy type:                    nginx
```

I've exposed container port `8000` because daphne runs on port `8000` by default:

```
app[socket.1]: Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
app[socket.1]: Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
app[socket.1]: Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
```

But I'm unable to connect to my websocket in the browser. I get a `Not Found: /ws/mywebsocket` error for my websocket endpoint, and `socket.onclose` function immediately gets called with a `code: 1006`.

I think I need to create a custom nginx.sigil for dokku to redirect to the websocket if the url contains `/ws/`, but a lot of the answers seem out of date and not working.

Answer (score 1):

The port mapping system in Dokku passes the port mappings along to the individual proxy implementations, which must handle the scheme. The built-in nginx proxy plugin only supports `http` and `http` port mappings. Additionally, it does not have any functionality to send connections from a given port mapping to a given process type.

The nginx proxy plugin exposes a custom `.DOKKU_APP_${PROCESS_TYPE}_LISTENERS` variable for each `PROCESS_TYPE` in your `Procfile`, which can be used in conjunction with a custom `nginx.conf.sigil` to:

- create a custom upstream block
- add a location block pointing at that upstream block

You might create the upstream block for your particular use case like so:

```
# the variable maps to the Procfile entry. Replace `SOCKET` as appropriate for your process type name.
{{ if $.DOKKU_APP_SOCKET_LISTENERS }}
# this assumes the socket listening port is 8000
upstream {{ $.APP }}-socket-8000 {
{{ range $listeners := $.DOKKU_APP_SOCKET_LISTENERS | split " " }}
{{ $listener_list := $listeners | split ":" }}
{{ $listener_ip := index $listener_list 0 }}
  server {{ $listener_ip }}:8000;{{ end }}
}
{{ end }}
```

The location block would then look like so:

```
location /ws/ {
  proxy_pass http://{{ .APP }}-socket-8000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```